# How to create public static object inside a Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, avplayer

Can anybody tell me how to create a public static object from `AVPlayer` class inside a view controller? I defined it in .m class this way. But cannot access it from another view controller. Please tell me how to access this `AVPlayer` object from another view controller

```
@implementation MainPlayerViewController
@synthesize arrayCurrentSongList,currentSongID;
static AVPlayer *newPlayer=nil;
```

Comment: make it a property in h file

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)static AVPlayer *player ? this doesnt allowed me to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add accessor method to you `MainPlayerViewController` interface

`+ (AVPlayer*)sharedPlayer;`

and implement it like

`+ (AVPlayer*)sharedPlayer { return newPlayer; }`

Then you can call `[MainPlayerViewController sharedPlayer]` from wherever you import your MainPlayerViewController.h.

However you should make static variables only when you really have to, which is likely not the case here.

Comment: to where do I need to add this + (AVPlayer*)sharedPlayer;

Comment: Place it inside `@interface MainPlayerViewController` in your MainPlayerViewController.h file. Do you actually have any knowledge of what Objective C is?..